Drupal Module Upgrade Conflict Address & Commerce
I am facing an issue while trying to upgrade drupal module due to module dependencies on other module.
composer require 'drupal/address:^2.0'
composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.38'

when i try to run one of above command, it failed due to conflict issue because these modules have dependencies on each other on specific version.


can you guide me how can i resolve these issue?
I have tried composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.38' -W (with all dependencies) but same issue.
And when i run composer update 'drupal/commerce' -W , it just update some other package but do not resolve my issue


can you try composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.38' -W (with all dependencies)

or actually just composer update 'drupal/commerce' -W as you have it already installed

Hi @johnSmith, i have updated my question and both option did not work out.

Okay, then you need to update both requirements in one statement, e.g  composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.38' 'drupal/address:^2.0' -W or you manually remove drupal/adress from your root composer.json and run composer update 'drupal/commerce' -W

This issue got resolved from below command suggested by @johnsmith
composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.38' 'drupal/address:^2.0' -W

